# Can I add a button from the Ankh SVN toolbar to my toolbar in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, svn

I've created a custom toolbar in Visual Studio to run my external tool that builds the solution and performs a commit using TortoiseSVN. After that, the Ankh SVN status in the project explorer is outdated since Ankh still does not feature any auto-refresh. I could also show Ankh's own toolbar, but I only need the refresh button of it. So I thought I'd just add that button to my toolbar to keep it clean.

After lots of searching I found Ankh's commands in the customize dialog in the "File" category. But the commands are alwys disabled in my toolbar, even though they're enabled in the standard context menus. What's wrong with these buttons?

Alternative: Are there better (free) Subversion extensions for VS 2010 that can auto-refresh on local status changes outside of VS?

Answer (score 0):

The AnkhSVN commands are context sensitive. In some cases there are 3 or 4 different versions of commands that would be used in different places in context menus depending on the state (Show History is an example that has different versions). If you pick the right version of a command it should work just fine in a toolbar.

You probably want the refresh from the pending changes window as that is +- stateless. (See also the 'Source Control-Subversion' toolbar)